# Why the command \n don't put the numbers in order when jumps the line?

Tags: c

I have doubt about my code, every time that I write when I compile it to run the numbers don't get in a line, is always down the hill but I use the command `\n` that should be able to put in a new line down the upper one, right?

I write this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("1 \n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n 5 \n 6 \n 7 \n 8 \n 9 \n 10 \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are asking why the numbers aren't aligned in the same column, it's because you include a space after each `\n`, which will indent everything by one character.

Comment: What is the expected output? What output do you see?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was automatic, I didn't realize that space would be the reason.

Comment: @Andr3Jun10r And `\n` is **not** a command. It's a character. Newline character to be exact.

Comment: @ rootkea It is a simple escape-sequence which is part of the character-literal family if you want to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

You add a space before and after the newline character `\n`.  This causes the second and subsequent lines to be indented by one space.

Use this instead if you want all numbers left aligned:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and this if you want them right aligned:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf(" 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n 5\n 6\n 7\n 8\n 9\n10\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can break the string into smaller chunks to make the intent more obvious:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf(" 1\n"
           " 2\n"
           " 3\n"
           " 4\n"
           " 5\n"
           " 6\n"
           " 7\n"
           " 8\n"
           " 9\n"
           "10\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use the formatting features of `printf` to do this in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        /* left pad the number with spaces for a minimum width of 2 characters */
        printf("%2d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```